# iOS 7, resize UINavigationController, keep UINavigationbar 64px height

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uistatusbar

My viewcontrollers hierarchy is: UIViewController -> UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController.

I want to show a banner moving down and shrinking UITabBarController. My problem is when I want to hide the banner and put to UITabBarController view the original frame, UINavigationBar doesn't extend to 64px as it has before. It keeps 44px height and leaves a blank space of 20px (status bar height).

I tried to move directly the navigation controller but it behaved worst than this approach. I checked frames and they have the correct values dispite of UINavigationbar height.

Is there any solution to this?